# Compare two numbers and set a value of 1 or 0 to the Highest or Lowest in Excel or SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a list of players and a list of their scores in a game. I'd like to compare the two columns, and return a value of 1 or 0. 1 = Highest number, 0 = Lowest number. If the two values are equal, I'd like to return two 1's.

How can I do this using Excel or SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data.

Comment: If I've understood your question correctly, you could simply use =IF(A1>=B1,1,0) in column C1 and  =IF(A1<=B1,1,0) in column D1. This would give you 1 where A>B and A=B and the same for B>A and B=A

Comment: Check out `case` expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want the player with the highest score in a team to be marked with 1 and the lowest with 0. In that case:

```
SELECT t.team_id,t.player_id,t.score,
       case when t.score = s.max_score then 1
            when t.score = s.min_score then 0
       end as pro_ind
FROM YourTable t
INNER JOIN(select team_id,max(score) as max_score,min(score) as min_score
           FROM YourTable
           GROUP BY team_id) s
 ON (t.team_id = s.team_id)
```

Of course I guessed the names of the columns, so you will have to adjust it.